# While read line is very slow

Tags: linux, bash, loops, while-loop

I want to create thumbs for large list of images.
The problem is, it appears that while read line is very slow with large lists. one solution that i can think of is to create files that contain max 500 lines and then read them one by one. but is there any smart solution for this problem?

```
while read line; do
  if [ -e "$line" ] && [ ! -z "$line" ]; then
              ...
  fi
}
done <<< "$imagesList"
```

Comment: Maybe use something more suited for these tasks than bash?

Comment: Also, where do you get `$imagesList` from and why do you pass it in with `<<<`? Maybe you could just pipe whatever creates that list into `xargs` instead.

Comment: @millimoose imagesList is a result from find.

Comment: I *highly* doubt that what's slow here is reading the lines. You're creating a thumbnail image for each file? *That's* the slow part.

Comment: My intuition is the slow part is building the long-ass string from the `find` command then splitting it into lines again. Do `find ... | (while read line; do; ...; done)` instead.

Comment: @ruakh Good point, I guess I was blinded by the inefficiency in the code at hand to notice it won't matter.

Comment: For a savings of a few milliseconds, don't put the while loop in a subshell: `find ... | while read line; ...` will suffice.

Comment: No offense, but this comment thread is full of cargo-culting and there's not enough observable from the question to really confirm or deny any approach. Most likely `find … -exec something {} +` is a more appropriate approach than *anything* involving a `while loop`, but it's impossible to compose that answer without more information in the question.

Comment: btw, if `imagesList` is anyway being generated from `find`, why again check for `[ -e "..." ]` or `[ !-z "..." ]`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using a HERE string to read in these lines via `<<<`. This will be slow if the HERE string is very large.

If `$imgageList` is a file, you can do a file redirect and this will be a lot faster:

```
while read line
do
    if [ -e "$line" -a ! -z "$line" ]
    then
       ...
    fi
done < "$imagesList_file"  # Redirect from a file.
```

You might be able to do this:

```
echo "$imagesList" | while read line
    do
    if [ -e "$line" -a ! -z "$line" ]
    then
       ...
    fi
done
```

But, I would be worried about overloading the command line. In Linux/Unix systems, this is defined in the `/usr/include/sys/syslimits.h` or `/usr/include/syslimits.h`. It's 1024 * 256 on my system or 262,144 bytes. This sounds like a lot, but can be deceptive. File names can be quite long -- especially if you include the directory path in them. This is usually long enough to pass when you're testing, but fail when you really, really are depending upon it to work. And. it fails silently. You never know that the last few file names were dropped off.

Your best bet is to create a file with the list of image names instead of loading them up in an environment variable.

Comment: Overloading *what* on the commandline? ARG_MAX is the maximum length of the buffer passed to `exec`, which shouldn't affect a pure bash solution if you can avoid a subshell. If you do create a subshell, I think the speed of `echo | while read` is pretty suspect since you've also got `PIPE_BUF` limiting the buffer size of the pipe.

Comment: ARG_MAX is also the maximum length that can fit in the command line -- once the command line is expanded. The shell expands the command line and passes it to the command. If `$imagesList` is large, it may be too big to pass to the executing command. PIPE_BUF isn'e a limiting factor. In fact, on my system, it's only 512 bytes. PIPE_BUF is used to hold data that the first command's STDOUT to the second command's STDIN if the second command isn't ready for it. I can certainly pass more than 512 bytes through a pipe.

Comment: I didn't mean `PIPE_BUF` limited the *amount*, just the *speed*. But let's ignore that point. The more critical thing here is that `ARG_MAX` is the maximum length that can fit in the command line *only* when the shell is invoking something via `exec`. If the shell is invoking a builtin, such as in a loop, `ARG_MAX` does not apply. As is the case here.

Answer (score -1):

Let's try again:

```
echo $imagelist | xargs --delimiter=\  --max-args=1 -i echo "Do something with {}"
```

--- 8< First version --- 8< ---

Try something like this:

```
for IMG in $imageList; do
    echo "Do something with ${IMG}"
done
```

--- >8 First version --- >8 ---

Comment: If `$imageList` is as big as the OP says it is, this will be very slow and will probably overload the command line which means the last entries won't be executed.